# Why does the main component get rendered if its not part of the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const PrimaryLayout = () => (
  <div className="primary-layout">
    <header>
    {console.log("homepage")}
      Our React Router 4 App <Link to='/'>Home</Link>    <Link to='/users'>Users</Link>
    </header>
    <main>
      <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/users" component={UsersPage} />
    </main>
  </div>
)

const HomePage =() => <div>Home Page</div>
const UsersPage = () => <div>Users Page</div>

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
      <PrimaryLayout />
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

in the header i have included a console log to see if the header get rerendered when the url changes, it does. my question is this:

Why does it get rendered when its outside of the routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className="primary-layout">
<header />                                      //Render always
<main>
  <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} /> // Render only when path is /
  <Route path="/users" component={UsersPage} /> // Render only when path is /users
</main>
```

1. In your code, the `Primarylayout` falls inside the `BrowserRouter`. So it is *inside* the routing, not outside.
2. Even if it weren't whatever you define within the JSX file will be rendered, as long as it is in the render function.

If you have a router defined, then whatever is conditional (`Route`) will be rendered conditionally i.e. when the `path`s match. Whatever is outside the conditional tags will be rendered anyway, like any normal component.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! that makes sense now. Will accept answer when allowed